# Prove the series has positive integer coefficients

Tags: recurrence-relations, algebraic-number-theory, power-series, integers

How can I show that the Maclaurin series for
$$
\mu(x) = (x^4+12x^3+14x^2-12x+1)^{-1/4}
\\
= 1+3\,x+19\,{x}^{2}+147\,{x}^{3}+1251\,{x}^{4}+11193\,{x}^{5}+103279\,
{x}^{6}+973167\,{x}^{7}+9311071\,{x}^{8}+\cdots
$$
has positive integer coefficients?  (I have others to do, too, but this one will be a start.)

**possibilities**
(a) The coefficients $Q(n)$ satisfy the recurrence
$$
(n+1)Q(n)+(12n+21)Q(n+1)+(14n+35)Q(n+2)+(-12n-39)Q(n+3)+(n+4)Q(n+4) = 0
$$
(b) $\mu(x)$ satisfies the differential equation
$$
(x^3+9x^2+7x-3)\mu(x)+(x^4+12x^3+14x^2-12x+1)\mu'(x)=0
$$
(c) factorization of $x^4+12x^3+14x^2-12x+1$ is
$$
\left( x-\sqrt {5}+3+\sqrt {15-6\,\sqrt {5}} \right)  \left( x-\sqrt 
{5}+3-\sqrt {15-6\,\sqrt {5}} \right)  \left( x+\sqrt {5}+3-\sqrt {15+
6\,\sqrt {5}} \right)  \left( x+\sqrt {5}+3+\sqrt {15+6\,\sqrt {5}}
 \right) 
$$
(d) $(1-8X)^{-1/4}$ has positive integer coefficients, But if $X$ is defined by $1-8X=x^4+12x^3+14x^2-12x+1$, then $X$ does not have integer coefficients.

(e) Can we compute the series for $\log\mu(x)$
$$3\,x+{\frac {29}{2}}{x}^{2}+99\,{x}^{3}+{\frac {3121}{4}}{x}^{4}+{
\frac {32943}{5}}{x}^{5}+{\frac {348029}{6}}{x}^{6}+\dots
$$
and then recognize that its exponential has integer coefficients?

Comment: It can be seen that $\mu^{4} = (x+1)^{2} \, ((x+1)^{2} + 8x) - 8 \, x \, ((x+1) + 2)$. By making use of AM-GM it may be possible to show that the series is positive in nature. As to the ability to show each coefficient is positive then $4^{th}$ order difference equation needs to be utilized.

Comment: It is interesting that the coefficients are all odd too. We can prove that if we use the definition of extended binomial coefficients, that $\dbinom{-1/4}{k}$ has denominator that is a power of $2$ if that helps.

Comment: Do you know whether the specific integer coefficients of the 4th degree polynomial $p(x)$ actually matter in determining whether the Taylor series of $(p(x))^{1/4}$ has all integer coefficients or not? I.e. maybe the Taylor series always has integer coefficients as long as $p(x)$ does, and $p(0)$ is a perfect 4th power. A handful of trials with a computer math tool, getting say, 20 degree Taylor polynomials with different choices of $p(x)$ could help answer this. The reason why I bring this up is it could help guide a proof to know exactly what assumptions are required to prove the claim.

Comment: @user2566092 Of course $(1-x)^{-1/4}$ does not have integer coefficients. Nor does $(1-2x)^{-1/4}$ or $(1-4x)^{-1/4}$.  You have to go to $(1-8x)^{-1/4}$ for this.

Comment: I can do positivity.  If there are no solutions, I will post that in a few days.

Comment: @SandeepSilwal ... Not only are the coefficients all odd, but they repeat $1,3,9,7$ mod 10.  Explain that!

Answer (score 4):

I can prove the integer property, but not (yet) positivity.

**Lemma**: *The coefficients of Taylor series of $\mu(x)$ are integers*.

**Proof**. We can write
$$x^4+12x^3+14x^2-12x+1=\left(1-x\right)^4\Bigl(1-8\nu(x)\Bigr),$$
where $\nu(x)$ is given by
$$\nu(x)=\frac{2}{1-x}-\frac{7}{\left(1-x\right)^2}+\frac{7}{\left(1-x\right)^3}-\frac{2}{\left(1-x\right)^4}.$$
The coefficients of Taylor series of $\nu(x)$ are clearly integer and we have $\nu(0)=0$. Since the coefficients of $(1-x)^{-1}$ and $(1-8x)^{-\frac14}$ are integers, the statement follows. $\qquad\square$

Another option is to rewrite $\mu(x)$ in terms of $y=\frac{x}{1-x}$:
$$\mu(x)\mapsto \frac{1+y}{\left[1-8y\left(1-y^2\right)\left(1+2y\right)\right]^{\frac14}}.$$
It is interesting to note that even the coefficients of different powers of $y$ seem to be positive.

Comment: Great.  This also works on my previous case... $(x^2-34x+1)^{-1/2}$ and the next case $(x^4+228x^3+494x^2-228x+1)^{-1/4}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof for positivitiy.  Use the recurrence
$$
(n+1)Q(n)+(12n+21)Q(n+1)+(14n+35)Q(n+2)+(-12n-39)Q(n+3)+(n+4)Q(n+4) = 0
$$
$Q(0)=1,Q(1)=3,Q(2)=19,Q(3)=147$.  Prove by induction that
$Q(n) \ge 3 Q(n-1)$ for $n \ge 1$.  This is true for the first few terms.
Assume true up to $Q(n+3)$, then prove it for $Q(n+4)$ as follows:
$$
(n+4)Q(n+4) = (12n+39)Q(n+3)-(14n+35)Q(n+2)-(12n+21)Q(n+1)-(n+1)Q(n)
\\
\ge \left[(12n+39)-\frac{14n+35}{3}-\frac{12n+21}{9}-\frac{n+1}{27}\right]Q(n+3)
\\
=\left[\frac{161}{27} n + \frac{692}{27}\right] Q(n+3)
\gt (3n+12)Q(n+3)=(n+4)3Q(n+3)
$$
and therefore $Q(n+4) > 3 Q(n+3)$.

Answer (score 2):

For the periodicity mod $5$, note that 
$$(1 - x^4)^4 \equiv (1 + 3 x + 4 x^2 + 2 x^3)^4 (1-12 x+14 x^2+12 x^3+x^4) \mod 5 $$
and thus
in the field $\mathbb Z_5((x))$ of formal Laurent series in $x$ over the integers mod $5$ we have
$$ \eqalign{&\dfrac{1}{1-12 x+14 x^2+12 x^3+x^4} = \left(\dfrac{1+3x+4x^2+2x^3}{1-x^4}\right)^4\cr 
&= \left(1+3x+4x^2+2x^3 + (1+3x+4x^2+2x^3) x^4 + (1+3x+4x^2+2x^3) x^8 + \ldots  \right)^4\cr} $$

Given there is a solution over the integers, taking the coefficients mod $5$ gives us a solution in $\mathbb Z_5((x))$.  Of course there are four fourth roots, but this is the only solution whose constant coefficient is $1$ (the others have $2, 3$ or $4$).

Similarly, to show the coefficients are odd, 
$$(1-x)^4 \equiv 1 + x \equiv 1 -12 x + 14 x^2 + 12 x^3 + x^4 \mod 2$$
so that in $\mathbb Z_2((x))$
$$\dfrac{1}{1-12 x+14 x^2+12 x^3+x^4} = \dfrac{1}{(1-x)^4} = (1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots)^{4}$$

Combine the solutions mod $5$ and mod $2$ and we see that mod $10$ the coefficients repeat $1,3,9,7$.

The pattern mod $3$ also seems quite interesting (but not periodic): I'll leave that as an exercise.  Solution tomorrow if nobody else posts it.

EDIT: OK, time's up.  Mod $3$ we have 
$$\eqalign{(1 - x^2 + x^4)^{-1/4} &\equiv 1+{x}^{2}+{x}^{6}+{x}^{8}+{x}^{18}+{x}^{20}+{x}^{24}+{x}^{26}
\ldots\cr
&= \prod_{j=0}^\infty \left(1 + x^{2\cdot 3^j}\right) = \sum_{k \in S} x^{k}\cr}$$
where $S$ is the set of positive integers whose base-3 representation contains no $1$'s.  This is because
$$(1+x^{m})^3 \equiv 1 + x^{3m}$$ so that
$$ \dfrac{1+x^{2\cdot 3^{n+1}}}{1+x^2} \equiv \prod_{j=0}^n \dfrac{1+x^{2\cdot 3^{j+1}}}{1+x^{2\cdot 3^j}} \equiv \prod_{j=0}^n \left(1 + x^{2\cdot 3^j}\right)^2$$
Taking $n \to \infty$ we get
$$ \dfrac{1}{1+x^2} \equiv \prod_{j=0}^\infty \left(1 + x^{2\cdot 3^j}\right)^2$$
and then 
$$ \dfrac{1}{1-x^2 + x^4} \equiv \dfrac{1}{(1+x^2)^2} \equiv 
\prod_{j=0}^\infty \left(1 + x^{2\cdot 3^j}\right)^4 $$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an "almost" solution for integer coefficients.

The zeros of $x^4+12x^3+14x^2-12x+1$ are algebraic integers.  So are their reciprocals.  Now in the series
$$
(1-xa)^{-1/4} = 1+\frac{a}{4} x+\frac{5 a^2}{32} x^2 +\frac{15a^3}{128} x^3 + \cdots
$$
where $a$ is an algebraic integer, the coefficients are algebraic integers (except for power-of-2 denominators).  Multiply four of these
$$
(x^4+12x^3+14x^2-12x+1)^{-1/4} = \prod_a (1-xa)^{-1/4}
$$
where the product is over all $a$ such that $1/a$ is a zero of $x^4+12x^3+14x^2-12x+1$.  Its coefficients are also algebraic integers, except possibly for power-of-2 denominators.  But this is invariant under permutation of the roots, so the coefficients are rational numbers.  (We can also see this more directly.)  Therefore the coefficients are rational integers, except possibly for power-of-2 denominators.

After doing this, I thought I would be able to finish by using 2-adic numbers, to analyze these denominators.  But it seems this polynomial has no 2-adic zeros.  So I would have to go to an algebraic extension of the 2-adics...